# VBA Runtime Error 9 when checking whether String has two parts

Tags: string, vba, split, runtime-error

I am working with cells in a column, which have to be split. Element 1 of the string is supposed to be posted separately from Element 2 of the same string, each on another Worksheet.

**String "123 ABC" -> "123" in column C and "ABC" in column D**

I am running into a Runtime-Error 9 "Index out of Range" if one of the cells I am checking only contains "123" or "ABC" but no both parts.

I tried to work around it in the way you see in my code below. Needless to say it does not work.

Could one of the more experienced Excel-Gurus help me out here? 
Thank you in advance for your time!

[image]

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbInput As Workbook, wbOutput As Workbook
Set wbOutput = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet, wsMistakes As Worksheet
Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Worksheets("FehlerVorkommen")
Set wsMistakes = wbOutput.Worksheets("NichtZuweisbar")
Dim lRowInput As Long, lRowOutput As Long, lRowMistakes As Long
Dim Lieferant As Range
Dim InputFile As String, myElements() As String

lRowOutput = wsOutput.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsOutput.Range("A2:G" & lRowOutput).Clear
wsMistakes.Range("A2:G500").Clear

InputFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

If InputFile = "Falsch" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wbInput = Workbooks.Open(InputFile)
Set wsInput = wbInput.Worksheets("owssvr")
lRowInput = wsInput.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Get all Information
For Each Lieferant In wsInput.Columns(1).Rows("2:" & lRowInput)

    If wsInput.Columns(3).Rows(Lieferant.Row) <> vbNullString Then

        myElements = Split(wsInput.Columns(3).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Value, " ", 2) 'A maximum of 2 String-Parts to avoid 4-5 splits whenever there is a GmbH or AG or whatever

        If IsEmpty(myElements(1)) = True Then <<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE<<<<<<<<<<<
            lRowMistakes = wsMistakes.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            NextRow = lRowMistakes + 1
            wsInput.Columns(1).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Copy Destination:=wsMistakes.Columns(1).Rows(NextRow)
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        Else

            If IsNumeric(wsInput.Columns(1).Rows(Lieferant.Row)) = True And wsInput.Columns(1).Rows(Lieferant.Row) <> vbNullString _
            And IsNumeric(wsInput.Columns(2).Rows(Lieferant.Row)) = True And wsInput.Columns(2).Rows(Lieferant.Row) <> vbNullString Then

                wsInput.Columns(1).Rows("2:" & lRowInput).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Columns(1).Rows("2:" & lRowInput) 'Task Namen
                wsInput.Columns(2).Rows("2:" & lRowInput).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Columns(2).Rows("2:" & lRowInput) 'Bestellpositionen
                wsOutput.Columns(3).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Value = myElements(0) 'ID
                wsOutput.Columns(4).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Value = myElements(1) 'Name
                wsInput.Columns(3).Rows("2:" & lRowInput).Copy Destination:=wsOutput.Columns(5).Rows("2:" & lRowInput) 'Fehlerarten

            Else 'Get all wrong inputs on separate Sheet
                lRowMistakes = wsMistakes.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                NextRow = lRowMistakes + 1
                wsInput.Columns(1).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Copy Destination:=wsMistakes.Columns(1).Rows(NextRow)
                NextRow = NextRow + 1
            End If

        End If

    Else 'Get all wrong input on separate Sheet
        lRowMistakes = wsMistakes.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        NextRow = lRowMistakes + 1
        wsInput.Columns(1).Rows(Lieferant.Row).Copy Destination:=wsMistakes.Columns(1).Rows(NextRow)
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
    End If

Next Lieferant

wbInput.Close
```

Comment: use InStr function to check if both values are in the string then do  the split if both return a value > 0

Comment: But both values are Elements of the string and if one is out of the index-range, it will give me an Error nonetheless. Or at least it did when I tried what you said. Could you give a code-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it's doing:

```
If IsEmpty(myElements(1)) = True
```

First, specifying a limit for the `Split` function doesn't mean that you always get that many elements in the array.  Second, `IsEmpty` tests to see if a `Variant` is type VT_EMPTY, not whether a `String` has a value (`Split` returns a strongly typed array).

Just test the `UBound` instead:

```
If UBound(myElements) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Your answer did the trick. Thank you! All I needed to do was switch the > to <=